# Expand an <a> tag to fill the space

Tags: html, css, xhtml

How can I make the anchor tag expand to the bottom of the list item?
I know I could put the anchor round the list item tag, but that breaks XHTML 1.0 Strict compliance, so I cannot do it.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #listWrapper { text-align:center;}
      #list { margin-left: 0px auto; margin-right: 0px auto; width: 100%; min-height: 100%; height:100%; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0px;}
      #list ul { padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px; margin: 0; min-height: 100%;}
      #list li { clear:both; font-weight:bolder; height:auto; border-bottom: 1px solid Silver; border-left: 1px solid Silver; font-size:x-small; border-right: 1px solid Silver; list-style-type: none;}
      #list a:hover { background-color: red;}
      #list a { display:block; cursor:pointer; text-decoration: none; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; }
      #list h3 { background-color:Silver; vertical-align:top; font-size:larger; }
      #list img { height:auto; margin: 8px; float:left; vertical-align:top; border:solid 1px Silver;}   
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="listWrapper">
      <div id="list">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h3>title</h3>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="/images/x.jpg" alt="" />
              Lorem ipsun........
            </a>
            <div style="clear:both;" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <h3>title</h3>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="/images/x.jpg" alt="" />
              Lorem ipsun........
            </a>
            <div style="clear:both;" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A combination of your answers fixed it.  Many thank....

```
#list ul { display: block; }
#list li { display: block;}
#list a { display:block; height:100%; }
```

Comment: #list a { display:block; height:100%; } fixed it for me.

Answer (score 12):

use this css:

```
#list ul li a { display: block }
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the

```
<br style="clear: both;"/>
```

inside the Anchor tag.

EDIT: changed div to br

Comment: that breaks XHTML 1.0 Strict compliance

Answer (score 1):

To fill the bottom, you need to fix the image margins - right now the image is taking up too much space with it's `8px` margin. To fill the top, you need to remove the bottom margin of `h3`.

```
#list h3 { margin-bottom: 0; }
#list img { margin: 5px 8px; }
```

Comment: Note that I tested this on my local laptop, with no access to the file `images/x.jpg`, so the margins I suggested are for an image of `1x1 px`. If your image is of a different size, you might need to adjust the margins differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try set height on the `#list` to a fixed size, and height on `#list a`to `100%`.

Differences to your existing code:

```
    #list
    {
        min-height: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    #list a
    {
         height:100%;
    }
```

Comment: ... but #list is not a fixed size - it varies.

Comment: The reason for this is that sometimes the browser does not understand what is the relative size if not at least one of the parents has fixed size. I think this is most an issue in Internet Explorer. But I'm glad you found the solution for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
<!-- teh codes -->
<style type="text/css">
  .nav-cell
  {
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0px; /* just to make sure the link will fill the entire cell */
    text-align: center;
    width: 92px;
  }
  .nav-cell-link
  {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .nav-cell-link-text
  {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 11px;
  }
</style>
<!-- teh codes -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 35px;">
  <tr>
    <td class="nav-cell">
      <a href="#" class="nav-cell-link">
        <span class="nav-cell-link-text">Link Text</span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- teh codes -->
```