# Unable to make A fill out li tag

Tags: css

Been trying to get this to work for a while now. I'm trying to create the menu for my new site, Ive set up the nav, ul, and li tags. Naturally, I have the actual buttons slightly larger than the text displaying, and I wish to have the A fill out the LI tag.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
}
nav a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: auto auto auto 10vw;
  height: 2em;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I feel like ive tried everything in:

[How do I make an <a> tag the size of it's parent <li> tag for larger clickable region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019231/how-do-i-make-an-a-tag-the-size-of-its-parent-li-tag-for-larger-clickable-r)

[Stretching <a> tag to fill entire <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264370/stretching-a-tag-to-fill-entire-li)

[Expand an <a> tag to fill the space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378718/expand-an-a-tag-to-fill-the-space)

and I really feel like my code should give the same result. Can someone please point out what mistake I've made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had the right idea by adding `display:block` on the anchors, however the padding on your list item was affecting the result. Move that padding onto the anchors and you're all set.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
}
nav a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: auto auto auto 10vw;
  height: 2em;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: And maybe add `box-sizing : border-box ;` so the anchors won't overflow.

Comment: Just about to say. It seems like the anchors shift right with each block

Comment: @PeaceDealer - I'm not seeing any shifting on Chrome or FF.

Comment: @PeaceDealer sorry, I'm not clear on what the image shows.

Comment: @j08691 The anchor tag extends outside the li tag, with quite abit. If i place my mouse a fair distance from the right most li tag it still hovers over it. Illustration: http://i.imgur.com/vq2lMBv.png

Comment: @PeaceDealer ah now I see what you're referring to, in which case LarsW's will adjust for that

Comment: Could you please put a reference for this?

Comment: @PeaceDealer - a reference? For the behavior of the box model?

Comment: @PeaceDealer - I'm referring to the first comment by LarsW: "add box-sizing : border-box ; so the anchors won't overflow"

Comment: Whopos, missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @PeaceDealer I updated my answer to include his suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from the ul li:

```
nav ul li {padding:0px;}
```

If necessary add it to the nav ul li a:

```
nav ul li a {padding:0px 50px;}
```